# How to analyze HTTP requests coming to debian linux machine

Tags: debian, packet-capture

I want to analyze the http traffic of a debian linux machine. I know that I can run fiddler on  any other machine and capture the traffic of that perticular machine. But the question is how.? and also are there any other, better, ways to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[catcher](https://github.com/ren85/catcher) currently in alpha, but should do the job decently

Answer (score 0):

You can use tcpdump to record incoming traffic (for example tcpdump -i eth0 "src 192.168.6.66 and dst port 80" -s 8129 -w http.dump) and analyze output file later on your desktop using wireshark.